# Alternative to Whatsapp that takes less phone storage space

Tags: chat, cloud-storage, whatsapp

I don't like it that much **whatsapp** because repeatedly fills the mobile memory.

Some recommendation to get that store automatically old conversations in its servers, without mine intervention.

Yes, I know that **Whatsapp** has Backup option. I don't want to do nothing about this. Like **Facebook** works (You don't need to store your conversation history).

What about **Telegram**?

Comment: WhatsApp already stores all data on its servers (like Facebook and Telegram). I guess each application caches different quantities of local information. How about Snapchat, which does not store data at all?

Comment: Be aware that, if using an "alternative to WhatsApp", your contacts must do the same. There are many alternatives available (and most are much more privacy friendly). But as long as the service is proprietary, all your contacts must use the same service (or you cannot "inter-communicate").

Answer (score 3):

WhatsApp can actually be configured to use much less phone space:

1. Go to the settings
2. Touch "Data and storage usage"
3. Find the "Media auto-download" section
4. In each of the items in that section, unselect everything
5. Delete everything in your `WhatsApp/Media` folder.

Now, WhatsApp should take no more than a megabytes or two, rather than hundreds of megabytes.